# building a NodeJs Express Router structure with Ajax POST

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax

I want to use the Express router for my project. I create my `app.js` (my view engine is Handlebars)

```
const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const app = express();

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));

require('./server/router')(app); // start with the routing

app.listen(8888);
```

and head over to my `router.js` where I handle all the route files

```
module.exports = function(app){
    var router = require('express').Router();

    app.use('/login', require('./routes/login'));
    app.use('/route2', require('./routes/route2'));
    app.use('/route3', require('./routes/route3'));

    router.post('/logout', function (req, res) { 
        var session = req.session;
        session.destroy();
        res.send({});
    });
};
```

My login route deals with two tasks:

- the route itself
- the Ajax call "validateLogin"

.

```
var router = require('express').Router(); // I set this on each route

router.get('/', function (req, res) { // render the HTML template
         res.render('login');
    });


router.post('/validateLogin', function (req, res) { // user login - AJAX

    var loginIsValid = true; // TEST // req.body.username && req.body.password
    res.send({
          isValid: loginIsValid
    });
});

module.exports = router; // export this module
```

The client has a simple login form. When pressing the login button I execute this Ajax call

```
function login() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'validateLogin',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: JSON.stringify({
            username: "Foo",
            password: "Bar"
        })
    }).done(function (response) {
        if (response.isValid) { // Redirect the user to the next page
            $(location).attr('href', 'next page');
        }
    }).fail(function () {

    });
}
```

This Ajax call fails because the POST route can't be found

> POST http://localhost:8888/validateLogin 404 (Not Found)

Even using

```
url: '/validateLogin',
```

does not work.

What is missing or wrong? Is my structure fine?

I took the information from

> http://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html

Comment: try `url: '/validateLogin',`

Comment: no, that did not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming all else is setup correctly, based on your code's setup it seems the url you want to access is actually located at `/login/validateLogin`

Comment: yes that worked, I thought my path could be relative. I always have to write `'/route/name'` ?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but this might be a quirk of Jquery Ajax or express in particular. It really depends on several factors and I'd suggest looking into it. However, try `./name` or `../name` and see if that works.